# "Overflow" compiler error with -9223372036854775808L

Tags: .net, vb.net, long-integer

The range of the [Long data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/long-data-type) is `-9223372036854775808` to `9223372036854775807`, but the following statement generates compiler error "BC30036: Overflow":

```
Dim a As Long = -9223372036854775808L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0vSTc4vSv3/3yUzVyFRwbFYwSc/L13BVkHX0sjI2NjcyMDYzMLUxNzc1MLAwuf/fwA)

Why is this an error? How can I specify the constant `-9223372036854775808` in code?

Comment: funny, it works in C#, but fails in vb

Comment: What error(with number) you got exactly?

Comment: What is the value of " Int64.MinValue"

Comment: Have you tried with other literal formats too, e.g. hex? Just curious.

Comment: I guess it's another odd VB6 compatibility issue, valid in .NET but not in visual basic

Comment: @Joshpbarron it's exactly `-9223372036854775808L`.

Comment: It is a compiler parser issue.  Nobody writes this code, they favor `Dim a = Long.MinValue`

Comment: It is showing overflow

Comment: The  Int64.minvalue is    -9223372036854775808

Comment: Represent a 32-bit signed integer

Comment: Represent a 32-bit signed integer OVERFLOW

Comment: This time, because the question content is good, we helped you to format it, but next time make sure that your question is good before asking. Read [asking], [help], [mcve] for more details. Also -- when someone suggest something in the comment, you should [edit] your question to add the information instead of replying in the comment section.

Comment: For those wanting to report this as a bug, all I can say is good luck as I did so many years ago. This issue existed in both C# and VB, but it was fixed in C# in I believe VS2008. You can easy work around the problem using the MinValue for code that you write. However, the default CodeDom serializer will proudly produce code for an Int64 property that the parser can not deal with. A potential workaround is to decorate the property with <DefaultValue(Int64.MinValue)> to prevent it from being serialized. If the default trick is not applicable, you end up writing a custom serializer.

Answer (score 9):

### Why is this an error?

The compiler parses the expression `-9223372036854775808L` as a unary minus operator applied to the decimal integer literal `9223372036854775808L`. According to the [VB.NET specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/language-specification/lexical-grammar#literals):

> A decimal integer literal is a string of decimal digits (0-9).

And:

> If an integer literal's type is of insufficient size to hold the integer literal, a compile-time error results.

`9223372036854775808L` is too large for a `Long`, so you get an overflow error.
(The minus sign isn't part of the integer literal.)

### How can I specify the constant -9223372036854775808 in code?

To specify `-9223372036854775808` literally, use a hexadecimal literal:

```
Dim a As Long = &H8000000000000000
```

The VB.NET specification alludes to this as well:

> Decimal literals directly represent the decimal value of the integral literal, whereas octal and hexadecimal literals represent the binary value of the integer literal (thus, &H8000S is -32768, not an overflow error).

Of course, for clarity you should probably just use `Long.MinValue` instead of a literal:

```
Dim a As Long = Long.MinValue
```

### What about C#?

As René Vogt pointed out, the equivalent statement compiles fine in C#:

```
long a = -9223372036854775808L;
```

That's because (unlike VB.NET) [C# supports this as a special case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#integer-literals):

> When a *decimal_integer_literal* with the value 9223372036854775808 (2^63) and no *integer_type_suffix* or the *integer_type_suffix* `L` or `l` appears as the token immediately following a unary minus operator token, the result is a constant of type `long` with the value -9223372036854775808 (-2^63). In all other situations, such a *decimal_integer_literal* is of type `ulong`.

Comment: Nice answer dude. :)

Comment: Then why does it not happen when you declare an Integer minimum value like - Dim min As Integer = -2147483648. The Int32.Min​Value = -2147483648. But no compile error.

Comment: @JaisG: The literal 2147483648 is parsed as a Long integer literal, then negated and successfully coerced back to Integer.

Comment: That's why it works with C#. The compiler uses UInt64.MaxValue when checking numeric literals: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#integer-literals

Comment: Another very confusing option is to use `UnsignedLongCharacter`: `Dim a As Long = -9223372036854775808UL`

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev: That also works, though in a roundabout way: Negating any `ULong` results in a `Decimal`, not `Long` or `ULong`.

Comment: @JaisG but it happens if you add an S to it, such as -32768S gives an error, but Int16.MinValue does not